# How to use ngx-walkthrough in ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

walkthrough in ionic 3,i installed it by npm,and imported in app.module.ts and after that want to use it in home page.There i am getting this error.
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.

Comment: Do yo use one of those modules BrowserAnimationModule, NoopAnimatioModule?

Comment: No,I am not using BrowserAnimationModule or NoopAnimatioModule.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to import `Module` into `app.module.ts`. Kindly let me know if that helps.

Comment: if i am not importing in app.module.ts i will get this error  No provider for ApplicationInitStatus!